# Do nitrogen and oxygen react to form nitric oxide or nitrous oxide?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Various sources claim different products for the reaction between nitrogen and oxygen:

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{N2 + O2 &-> 2 NO} \tag{R1} \\
\ce{2 N2 + O2 &-> 2 N2O} \tag{R2}
\end{align}
$$

Which nitrogen oxide is actually formed? Are nitric and nitrous oxides formed in variable amounts, but depending on certain reaction conditions one is produced predominantly?

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/21684/why-does-n%E2%82%82-react-with-o%E2%82%82-to-form-no-at-high-temperatures?rq=1

Comment: and: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/49842/can-i-convert-elemental-nitrogen-to-nitrous-oxide?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oxygen and nitrogen react to form nitric oxide. Following is from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitric_oxide):

> The uncatalyzed endothermic reaction of oxygen ($\ce{O2}$) and nitrogen ($\ce{N2}$), which is effected at high temperature ($\pu{>2000 °C}$) by lightning has not been developed into a practical commercial synthesis (see Birkeland–Eyde process):
>
> $$\ce{N2 + O2 -> 2 NO}$$

Why nitrous oxide is not formed can be explained through thermodynamics. For any chemical reaction to take place spontaneously, we look at a factor known as free energy available for that reaction. Gibbs's Free Energy is given by the equation:

$$\mathrm{\Delta G = \Delta H − T\Delta S}$$

The quantity $\ce{\Delta G}$ must be negative for a reaction to take
place spontaneously. Now, most of the nitrogen oxides are unstable with respect to molecular nitrogen and molecular oxygen and have a positive value for the Gibbs free energy change of formation. For the reaction $\ce{2N2 + O2 −>2N2O}$, we put the values in the equation and calculate the Gibbs Free energy to confirm that **this reaction can't take place.**

Now coming to our actual reaction, the entropy change is small and positive.

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{N2 + O2 -> 2NO}   & \tag{ΔG_0 = 86.7 kJ/mol}\\
\end{align}
$$

The Gibbs free energy change can also relate to the equilibrium constant, K.

$$\mathrm{G = -RT ln K = -5.7 log K~~(in~kJ~at~298 K)}$$

At equilibrium, that is under thermodynamic control, the concentration of $\ce{NO}$ in the atmosphere should be $\pu{10^-15.5 atm}$ but actual concentrations of $\ce{NO}$ are significantly higher than this (approximately $\pu{10^-10 atm}$).

So, even though thermodynamics says that $\ce{NO}$ is unstable with respect to $\ce{N2}$ and $\ce{O2}$, it doesn't spontaneously break down to those elements. There is a high activation barrier that must be overcome between reactants and products. Nitric oxide is kinetically stable but thermodynamically unstable.

For more information, please read the [article](http://butane.chem.uiuc.edu/pshapley/environmental/l16/1.html).

But the reaction doesn't stop here. It proceeds to form more more nitrogen oxides $\ce{NO_x}$. You can continue reading the article for more details.

Comment: Is the reaction $\ce{2N2 + O2 -> 2N2O}$
 wrong ?

Comment: @Eloise [well the reverse is true](http://chemiday.com/en/reaction/3-1-0-2265).

Comment: This is what I am confused out. I have seen the reaction in which $N_2O$ decomposes to $N_2$ and $O_2$ in many authentic sources but I have seen the reverse reaction on some online sources which may or may not be credulous. I need to be able to say with definiteness whether the reverse reaction is true or not.

Comment: @Eloise I edited the answer.

Comment: Throw in a little water vapor and you go all the way to nitric acid, which therefore exists in (unpoolluted) rainwater. Yuck, but also yum: the acid is both a source of fixed nitrogen and a reagent that releases other nutrients for plants by dissolving some minerals.